# What is the meaning of "\_" in output of 'ps ef'?

Tags: linux, ps

When I executed `ps ef` command in a linux server, I saw that one of the command starts with `\_`. 
For example,

```
\_ /bin/sh /usr/
```

Could any one please let me know what is the meaning of `\_` in this command?

Comment: I think you are confusing the BSD syntax and the standard syntax. Do you mean `ps -ef` instead of `ps ef`? Note the dash.

Comment: @lesmana `ps f` is the syntax that produces this output (in the default personality).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the child process of the parent process ID. Because ps ef will show you list processes in a hierarchy.

This is from `man ps`:

```
f     ASCII art process hierarchy (forest)
```